# C++ Debug Error: HEAP_CORRUPTION_DETECTED

Tags: c++, exception, runtime-error, syntax-error, visual-studio-debugging

[image: Visual Studio error is this;]

I don't know why i get this error.
But just i think problem occours when i create temporary object from dataclass.
When i create an object without argument, automatically size take 1.
Afterwards i set the temp.size = object's size. But i think it's temporarily sets the size.
When i try to call the sum_up function temp is equals to 1 again.
I don't know, just idea.
Can you help me?

This is my library file;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class dataclass {

private:
    int* data;
    int size;
public:
    dataclass(int size = 1) : size(size) {
        data = new int[size];
        cout << "Constructor works !" << endl;
        cout << "Created an array with" << size << " elements." << endl;
    }

    dataclass(const dataclass& k) {
        cout << "Copy constructor works! " << endl;
        this->size = k.size;
        data = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = k.data[i];
        }
        cout << "Created an arrray with " << k.size << " elements." << endl;
    }

    ~dataclass() { delete[] data; cout << "Destructor works. Array deleted" << endl; }

    const int* getData()const {
        return data;
    }

    int getSize() { return size; };
    void setSize(int size) { this->size = size; };
    void print()const
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << data[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void set(int idx, int value) {
        if (idx < size)
        {
            data[idx] = value;
        }
    }

    dataclass sum_up(const dataclass& k)const
    {
        if (size == k.size)
        {
            dataclass temp;
            temp.size = size;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                temp.data[i] = data[i] + k.data[i];
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
};
```

and the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DataClass.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    dataclass k(3); // create an array with 3 elements (blank now)
    for (int i = 0; i < k.getSize(); i++)
    {
        k.set(i, i+2); 
        /* 
           fill the array with for loop; set the index elements like this;
           set(0,2)
           set(1,3)
           set(2,4)
        */
    }
    k.print(); // print the array's elements.

    dataclass k1 = k; // copy constructor
    k.print(); // again print k values
    k1.print(); // and created by copy constructor k1's values.
    cout << endl << endl;

    (k.sum_up(k1)).print(); // sum up the data



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `sum_up` default-constructs `temp`, which means its `data` will have a size of 1. You then increase `temp.size` without allocating more memory for `data`. Your `setSize` member function is unsafe for the same reason.

Comment: Oh i gotch u 
`dataclass temp(size)`
When i create temp obejct like this, problem was solved. Thank you !

Comment: @Emir `int main() { dataclass d1(10);  dataclass d2(20);  d1 = d2; }` -- That simple program causes a double-delete error and a memory leak.  Your class suffers from not having a user-defined assignment operator.  Thus your `sum_up` code is broken right out-of-the-box, and your answer doesn't address this issue.

Comment: oh, so what should I do? Can you at least tell me the way I should go?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the way I was creating the `temp` object. Changing the code as follows fixed the problem:

```
    dataclass sum_up(const dataclass& k)const
    {
        if (size == k.size)
        {
            dataclass temp(size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                temp.data[i] = data[i] + k.data[i];
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
```